# PHP PDO didnt get data from database with $var

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am learning PDO and i want to retrieve data from my database. 
If i use constans in my query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `megoszt` INNER JOIN felhasznalok 
ON megoszt.f_id=felhasznalok.f_id 
INNER JOIN megosztas 
ON megoszt.m_id=megosztas.m_id WHERE nev LIKE 'exxor'
```

This works fine, but if i try with `$var` i didnt get result. What's wrong with this?

**Index.php**

```
<?php 

require_once 'database.php';
$db = new Database("localhost","root","","teszt");
$posztolo = $_SESSION['nev'];
$dataSet = $db->getFelhasznalo("SELECT * FROM `megoszt` INNER JOIN felhasznalok ON megoszt.f_id=felhasznalok.f_id INNER JOIN megosztas ON megoszt.m_id=megosztas.m_id where nev LIKE :posztolo");

if($dataSet) {
    foreach($dataSet as $data) { ?>
        <label>Megosztó</label> <?php echo ": ".$data->getFelhasznaloNev()."<br />[ ".$data->getMegosztasDatum()." ]"; ?><br />
        <label>Üzenet:</label><br /><?php echo $data->getFelhasznaloUzenet(); ?><br />
        <label>Megjelőlve:</label> <?php echo $data->getFelhasznaloTaguser(); ?><br />
        <?php echo "#".$data->getFelhasznaloTag(); ?> <p>
        <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo "Nincsenek megosztásaid!";
    } 

?>
```

**database.php**

```
<?php

require("ki.php");

class Database {
    private $con;

    public function __construct($host,$username,$password,$database) {

        $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$database,$username,$password);
    }

    public function getFelhasznalo($sql) {
        $statement = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(":posztolo", $nev, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
            $dataSet[] = new FelhasznaloAdat($row);
        }
        if(!empty($dataSet)) {
            return $dataSet;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**ki.php**

```
<?php

class FelhasznaloAdat {
    private $nev, $uzenet, $tag, $tag_user, $datum;

    public function __construct($dbRows) {

        $this->nev = $dbRows['nev'];
        $this->uzenet = $dbRows['uzenet'];
        $this->tag = $dbRows['tag'];
        $this->tag_user = $dbRows['tag_user'];
        $this->datum = $dbRows['datum'];
    }

    public function getFelhasznaloNev() {
        return $this->nev;
    }

    public function getFelhasznaloUzenet() {
        return $this->uzenet;
    }

    public function getFelhasznaloTag() {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    public function getFelhasznaloTagUser() {
        return $this->tag_user;
    }

    public function getMegosztasDatum() {
        return $this->datum;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You never set `$nev` in `getFelhasznalo` function

Comment: It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Why not use something like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) that's already complete and tested?

Comment: @tadman I'm learning university and i got this job.

Comment: That's great. I'm just suggesting two tools the might help you do your job better and with more confidence. Writing your own ORM can be a painful learning experience, there's a lot of things to get wrong. Using one off the shelf makes your code immediately familiar to anyone having to do maintenance on it in the future, and that person might even be you who's forgotten what you did before.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your help. I will check this tools and i hope this will help for me.